# PHP no hace los saltos de linea

Tags: php

Tengo este bucle:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($_SESSION["carrito"]) ; $x = $x + 1) {
    echo $_SESSION["carrito"][$x];
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

la salida esperada sería cada elemento, salto de línea, otro elemento..., sin embargo, no lo hace y sale todo junto y no entiendo porque. ¿Alguna idea?. He probado con código html 
 y si funciona, pero no entiendo porque no funciona con "\n".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nivel de consola los saltos de línea son asi

```
echo $_SESSION["carrito"][$x].PHP_EOL;
```

Mientras que a nivel de HTML los saltos de línea solo serán interpretados por ejemplo por la etiqueta `br`

```
echo $_SESSION["carrito"][$x]."<br/>";
```

Ya que está última es leída e interpretada por el navegador como un line break o instrucción para hacer un salto de línea

Comment: Justamente iba a explicar algo como eso. He decidido votar positivo porque cumple con lo que se requiere.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
echo $_SESSION["carrito"][$x].'<br/>';
```

Comment: Sí, funciona, pero la cuestión es porqué no lo hace bien con PHP

Comment: Podrías explicarme un poco como es que no lo hace bien?

Comment: Está explicado en la pregunta...